# How do I add an playable audio file to a TableListBox playlist (JUCE C++)

Tags: c++, file, user-interface, audio, juce

I want to click a button to open the file browser, open an audio file(mp3) which gets added to a table. I want it to be so that you can have multiple audio files available on the playlist table. I have some of it figured out, but I'm trying to create an event listener where I click a button, 'Add a track'. How can I populate my table or 'playlist' with the audio file? I have a file chooser already implemented that loads the file to be played and a play button that play a loaded file, I'm just not sure how to add it to the table? Any help is appreciated.
My code so far goes something along the lines of:

```
Array<File> trackTitles;
```

...

```
void PlaylistComponent::buttonClicked(Button* button)
{

    if (button == &loadButton)
    {
        DBG(" MainComponent::buttonClicked: loadButton");
        FileChooser chooser{ "Select a file" };
        if (chooser.browseForFileToOpen())
        {
            trackTitles.add(File{ chooser.getResult() });
            player->loadURL(File{ chooser.getResult() });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to provide some code. At least a snippet, ideally a minimal repro case that shows where you are. Otherwise it's really hard to help you out.

Comment: Where does PlaylistComponent inherit from?

Comment: In `JUCE/examples/GUI/WidgetsDemo.h` there is a demo showing how to create a table. You might want to have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

do you need to add a button to the table? here's an example

.h

```
    class PlaylistComponent : public juce::Component,
                              public TableListBoxModel,
                              public Button::Listener
    {
    .....
    Component *refreshComponentForCell(int rowNumber, int columnId, bool , Component *existingComponentToUpdate) override;
    void paintCell(Graphics &, int rowNumber, int columnId, int width, int height, bool ) override;
    void buttonClicked(Button *button) override;
    void setTracks(Array<File> tracksFile);


    TableListBox tableComponent;

    .....
    }
```

.cpp

```
PlaylistComponent::PlaylistComponent() 
{
    // In your constructor, you should add any child components, and
    // initialise any special settings that your component needs.
   
    tableComponent.getHeader().addColumn("", 1, 20);
    tableComponent.getHeader().addColumn("Track Title", 3, 500);
    tableComponent.setModel(this);
    addAndMakeVisible(tableComponent);
}


Component * PlaylistComponent::refreshComponentForCell(int rowNumber, int columnId, bool , Component *existingComponentToUpdate)
{
    
    if (columnId == ) // The ID and Length columns do not have a custom component
    {
        jassert(existingComponentToUpdate == nullptr);
        return nullptr;
    }

    if(columnId == 1)
    {
        // Creating component if does not existst yet

        TextButton * btn = static_cast<TextButton *> (existingComponentToUpdate);

        if (btn == 0)
        {
            btn = new TextButton { "Play" };
        }


        String id{ std::to_string(rowNumber) };
        btn->setComponentID(id);
        btn->addListener(this);
        existingComponentToUpdate = btn;
      
    }
    return existingComponentToUpdate;
   
}
void PlaylistComponent::paintCell(Graphics &g, int rowNumber, int columnId, int width, int height, bool )
{
    if (columnId == 2) {
        g.drawText(trackTitles[rowNumber], 2, 0, width - 4, height, Justification::centredLeft, true);
    }
    
}

void PlaylistComponent::setTracks(Array<File> tracksFile)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < tracksFile.size(); i++)
    {
        trackTitles.push_back(tracksFile[i].getFileName());
      
    }
    tableComponent.updateContent();

}

void PlaylistComponent::buttonClicked(Button *button)
{


   //Array<File> file;
   player->loadURL(file[std::stoi(button->getComponentID().toStdString())]); // your player
   player->start();

   
}
```

then near the table there should be a button for loading a lot of audio file, you can store it in a vector

```
Array<File> file;
..........
void loadAudioFiles()
{
    juce::String filters = "*.mp3";
    FileChooser chooser("Select an mp3 files..", File::getSpecialLocation(File::userHomeDirectory), filters);

   
    if (chooser.browseForMultipleFilesToOpen())
    {
        file = chooser.getResults();
        playlistComponent.setTracks(file );

    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be in the table, this is extremely helpful. I'm however having an issue now in the loadAudioFiles() function, where setTracks takes the file result as an argument I recieve an error "no suitable user defined conversion'juce::Array...' to 'std::vector...'". I am assuming because setTracks takes a vector but the file in the loadAudioFiles function must be an Array to get the results from the file chooser? Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: sorry  , change  void PlaylistComponent::setTracks(std::vector<File> tracksFile)
 to  void PlaylistComponent::setTracks(Array<File> tracksFile)
'

Comment: void setTracks(std::vector<File> tracksFile) change to  void setTracks(Array<File> file);